# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'merkmale_filter.source_id' in 'on clause', query was: INSERT INTO `qz8v_search_tmp_5fd7a0fb910a15_37972217`

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.4

Please help me fix this issue

```
main.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'merkmale_filter.source_id' in 'on clause', query was: INSERT INTO `qz8v_search_tmp_5fd7a0fb910a15_37972217` SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`, SUM(score) AS `relevance` FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  `search_index`.`entity_id`, (((0) + (0) + (0) + (0)) * 1) AS `score` FROM `qz8v_catalog_product_index_eav` AS `search_index`
 INNER JOIN `qz8v_cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_index` ON stock_index.product_id = search_index.entity_id AND `stock_index`.`website_id` = 0 AND `stock_index`.`stock_status` = 1 AND `stock_index`.`stock_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN (SELECT `entity_id`, `store_id`, `attribute_id`, `value` FROM qz8v_catalog_product_index_eav WHERE `attribute_id`=187 AND `store_id`=1 GROUP BY CONCAT(`entity_id`," ",`attribute_id`," ",`store_id`," ",`value`) ) AS `merkmale_filter` ON `search_index`.`entity_id` = `merkmale_filter`.`entity_id` AND `merkmale_filter`.`attribute_id` = 187 AND `merkmale_filter`.`store_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN (SELECT `entity_id`, `store_id`, `attribute_id`, `value` FROM qz8v_catalog_product_index_eav WHERE `attribute_id`=169 AND `store_id`=1 GROUP BY CONCAT(`entity_id`," ",`attribute_id`," ",`store_id`," ",`value`) ) AS `stoff_filter` ON `search_index`.`entity_id` = `stoff_filter`.`entity_id` AND `stoff_filter`.`attribute_id` = 169 AND `stoff_filter`.`store_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `qz8v_cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `merkmale_filter_stock_index` ON merkmale_filter_stock_index.product_id = merkmale_filter.source_id AND `merkmale_filter_stock_index`.`website_id` = 0 AND `merkmale_filter_stock_index`.`stock_status` = 1 AND `merkmale_filter_stock_index`.`stock_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `qz8v_cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stoff_filter_stock_index` ON stoff_filter_stock_index.product_id = stoff_filter.source_id AND `stoff_filter_stock_index`.`website_id` = 0 AND `stoff_filter_stock_index`.`stock_status` = 1 AND `stoff_filter_stock_index`.`stock_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN (SELECT `entity_id`, `store_id`, `attribute_id`, `value` FROM qz8v_catalog_product_index_eav WHERE `attribute_id`=99 AND `store_id`=1 GROUP BY CONCAT(`entity_id`," ",`attribute_id`," ",`store_id`," ",`value`) ) AS `visibility_filter` ON search_index.entity_id = visibility_filter.entity_id AND `visibility_filter`.`attribute_id` = 99 AND `visibility_filter`.`value` in ('2', '4') AND `visibility_filter`.`store_id` = '1'
 INNER JOIN `qz8v_catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `category_ids_index` ON search_index.entity_id = category_ids_index.product_id AND category_ids_index.store_id = '1' WHERE (search_index.store_id = '1') AND (category_ids_index.category_id in ('8')) AND (merkmale_filter.value  IN ('5526')) AND (stoff_filter.value  IN ('5448'))) AS `main_select` GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `relevance` DESC, `entity_id` DESC
 LIMIT 100000 [] []
[2020-12-14 17:33:27] main.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'merkmale_filter.source_id' in 'on clause', query was: INSERT INTO `qz8v_search_tmp_5fd7a1e746bd73_00356023` SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`, SUM(score) AS `relevance` FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  `search_index`.`entity_id`, (((0) + (0) + (0)) * 1) AS `score` FROM `qz8v_catalog_product_index_eav` AS `search_index`
 INNER JOIN `qz8v_cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_index` ON stock_index.product_id = search_index.entity_id AND `stock_index`.`website_id` = 0 AND `stock_index`.`stock_status` = 1 AND `stock_index`.`stock_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN (SELECT `entity_id`, `store_id`, `attribute_id`, `value` FROM qz8v_catalog_product_index_eav WHERE `attribute_id`=187 AND `store_id`=1 GROUP BY CONCAT(`entity_id`," ",`attribute_id`," ",`store_id`," ",`value`) ) AS `merkmale_filter` ON `search_index`.`entity_id` = `merkmale_filter`.`entity_id` AND `merkmale_filter`.`attribute_id` = 187 AND `merkmale_filter`.`store_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `qz8v_cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `merkmale_filter_stock_index` ON merkmale_filter_stock_index.product_id = merkmale_filter.source_id AND `merkmale_filter_stock_index`.`website_id` = 0 AND `merkmale_filter_stock_index`.`stock_status` = 1 AND `merkmale_filter_stock_index`.`stock_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN (SELECT `entity_id`, `store_id`, `attribute_id`, `value` FROM qz8v_catalog_product_index_eav WHERE `attribute_id`=99 AND `store_id`=1 GROUP BY CONCAT(`entity_id`," ",`attribute_id`," ",`store_id`," ",`value`) ) AS `visibility_filter` ON search_index.entity_id = visibility_filter.entity_id AND `visibility_filter`.`attribute_id` = 99 AND `visibility_filter`.`value` in ('2', '4') AND `visibility_filter`.`store_id` = '1'
 INNER JOIN `qz8v_catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `category_ids_index` ON search_index.entity_id = category_ids_index.product_id AND category_ids_index.store_id = '1' WHERE (search_index.store_id = '1') AND (`search_index`.`attribute_id` = 187) AND (`search_index`.`value` in ('5526')) AND (category_ids_index.category_id in ('8')) AND (merkmale_filter.value  IN ('5526'))) AS `main_select` GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `relevance` DESC, `entity_id` DESC
 LIMIT 100000 [] []
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `catalogsearch_fulltext` indexer must be in working state. You should reset that index first and than run reindexer. Than this issue is not going to occur.